# Getting values from dropdown and inputs in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get values from all the inputs.  I am able to get the input values from the inputs but not from the drop down the select tag.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      contacts
    };
  }

  removeContact(id) {
     const removedID = contact => contact.id !== id;
     const updatedContacts = this.state.contacts.filter(removedID)
     this.setState({contacts: updatedContacts})
  }

   handleSubmit(e){
     e.preventDefault(e)
     const target = e.target;
     console.log(target.email.value)
     console.log(target.gender.value)

   }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div>
              <label>
               First Name:
                 <input type="text" value={this.state.first_name} name="first_name" />
              </label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label>
               Last Name:
                 <input type="text" value={this.state.last_name} name="last_name" />
              </label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label>
               Email:
                 <input type="text" value={this.state.email} name="email"/>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <select value={this.state.gender} onChange={this.handleSubmit}> 
                  <option name="male"> Male</option>
                  <option name="female">Female</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </form>
```

Comment: Why do you submit the form on `onChange` of the select?

Comment: It wasn't working with or without it.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the `value` of the `select` to state, but don't change the state when a new value is selected. You need to `setState` once the value changes so that it's reflected in the DOM:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { gender: "male" };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ gender: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <select value={this.state.gender} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <option name="male"> Male</option>
        <option name="female">Female</option>
      </select>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Why don't I need to do this for the input feilds?

Comment: You will need it for the input fields as well. You can type into those fields now because `this.state.first_name` is undefined, you didn't set it in the constructor. If you set it you will see that you can't change the contents of it anymore because there's no `onChange` handler.

Comment: Understand I think... But on the    console.log(target.email.value) I am getting that value. Just not the gender one.

Comment: If you look at the state bound to those other input fields, e.g. this.state.email, without having an onChange to copy the mutated value back into the state, they will not change, they will still be the original unchanged values

Comment: If you set `name="gender"` on the select that will work, but it's not really the React way to do this as you're accessing the DOM directly. If you don't enjoy setting the state on every change you can [look into refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Comment: Thanks again for your detailed explanation. So much thanks